# Sending an Xcode Project file to a non Xcode User

Tags: c++, xcode

I created a small game in Xcode in Command Line Tool. I want to share it with my friend. My friend does not have Xcode. How can I share the project so that he can play the game without downloading the Xcode?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to send them the application you build from your project.

Comment: @molbdnilo I did not build the application just yet. I just created the game using the Command Tool Line, I think it is the only option that uses C++. How can I share it?